# Javascript(Jquery) input type submit or button conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

I want to hide a row after a delete query is done.

When i do this

```
<?php echo '<input type="submit" name="editProject'; echo $projectID; echo '" value="Edit" class="btn btn-success"/>';?>
```

The record will be deleted in the database but the row doesn't hide.

This

```
<input type="button"
```

Will hide the row but doesn't delete the record in the database.

So how can i delete a record in the database and hide that row together.

form in table:

```
<td class="deleterow"><form action="index.php" method="post">
    <?php echo '<button type="button" name="deleteProject'; echo $projectID; echo '" class="btn-sm btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>';?>
</form></td>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>

$(".deleterow").on("click", function(){
var $killrow = $(this).parent('tr');
    $killrow.addClass("danger");
$killrow.fadeOut(2000, function(){
    $(this).remove();
});});

</script>
```

Comment: `$(this).parent('tr');` only goes up 1 hierarchy level. Use `$(this).closest('tr')` instead

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an ajax call in order to achieve this functionality. I assume you have jQuery in your project.

```
$(".deleterow").on("click", function(){
var $killrow = $(this).parent('tr');
$killrow.addClass("danger");
$killrow.fadeOut(2000, function() {
    $(this).remove();

    $.post("delete.php", {id: "<?php echo $projectID; ?>"})
        .done(function(data) {
            alert("Project deleted: " + data);
        });
});
```

});

I only added this part.

```
$.post("delete.php", {id: "<?php echo $projectID; ?>"})
.done(function(data) {
    alert("Project deleted: " + data);
});
```

Comment: I just have this for my submit process `if(isset($_POST['deleteProject'.$projectID])){
           
$deleteProject = mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE from project
           WHERE project_id = '".$projectID."'")or die(mysqli_error($connection));
           }
` This is on the same page where the form is on called index.php do i just add this in a new file delete.php?

Comment: No you can call the index.php via ajax but it will return whole index page again as response. It would be better for you to use different files for ajax requests.